# Using an existing JDBC connection object with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to get Hibernate to connect to my MariaDB-database using an existing Connection-object that I either grab from a Tomcat connection pool or create via `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`. Both ways work, I receive a Connection object that I can perform both read and write operations with.
Now I want to supply these objects to Hibernate. I've chosen to do that like so:

```
public class SessionFactoryService implements ISessionFactoryService {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

private final Connection connection;

@Inject
public SessionFactoryService(Connection connection){

    this.connection = connection;
}

public Session getSession(){

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    SessionBuilder sb = sessionFactory.withOptions();

    return sb.connection(connection).openSession();
}}
```

When I call `getSession()`, I get a valid Session-object on which I can perform select-Statements in Hibernate. However, when i try to call `session.persist(someobj)`, i get the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections`

I have searched for people who've had the same issue for hours now without success, any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT1:

My hibernate configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name = "hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>

    <mapping class="com.xxx.yyy.Object"></mapping>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am only setting the dialect in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` since the connection objects are already set up externally.

The full stack trace looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:48)
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:452)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:782)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:767)
at com.xxx.yyy.ServiceA.create(ServiceA.java:75)
at com.xxx.yyy.App.main(App.java:60)
```

Comment: Could you provide your hibnernate configuration xml/java + a full  stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 return sb.openStatelessSession(connection);
```

or

```
 sessionFactory.withOptions().connection(Connection conn);
 return sb.openSession();
```